# Usage of validation set in neural networks

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to describe you an algorithm that I used to choose number of hidden layers and number of neurons within each of it (I couldn't find anywhere any approval of this approach, whereas it seems very logical for me):

1. Divide data into 60% (training), 20% (validation) and 20% (test) parts.

Now I want to check all possibilities in one hidden layer and two hidden layer network. To do so:

2. I'll train network with one hidden layer and with 1, 2 and 3 neurons within this one layer (3 different networks). After that I will calculate error on validation set (RMSE and MAE) for each of those networks.
3. I'll do exactly same thing for network with 2 hidden layers i.e. I'm gonna to estimate network with two hidden layers with all the possibilities of number of neurons in each layer (but number of neurons can only be 1, 2 or 3). It means that I will have 9 pairs of possible outcomes : 1 neuron in first hidden layer, 1 neuron in second hidden layer. 2 neurons in first hidden layer, 1 neuron in second hidden layer and so on... For each of the 9 architectures I'll calculate RMSE and MAE between predictions on validation set and actual values.
4. Out of all those iterations I'll pick the architecture for which error on the validation set is the lowest.

Could you please tell me if this algorithm make any sense? If not, what else I can do with validation set to choose the best architecture for neural network?

Answer (score 0):

This is the absolutely standard method of [hyperparameter/model selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html). The "trick" one relies upon is that you select from a very limited set of models (in your case 12), and thus your estimation of error will be very tight. You can refer to "statistical learning theory" book by Vladimir Vapnik giving you exact bounds why this sort of approach is great.

That being said you are working under the assumption that 20% of your data is "big enough" to estimate your performance, if it is not you can look at [Cross Validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)